# How can generate coverage report by module in gradle project?

Tags: gradle, jacoco

When i use maven-jacoco-plugin in multi proect,the coverage reports in the module dimension. for example: if the project has 3 modules like A,B,C , it can generated report by module.like this:A,B,C.

But if multi project organized by gradle, the coverage report will be in the package dimension.

So I want to see the gradle coverage report in the module dimension. How should I do it?